# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: RequestsServiceProvider <- RequestsService http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting above error In spite of defining my service name to all necessarily palaces.

here is my app.js

```js
var app = angular.module('ionicApp', [ 'ionic', 'ngCordova', 'checklist-model' ])

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  });

app.run([
  '$rootScope',
  'ngCart',
  'ngCartItem',
  'store',
  '$window',
  '$ionicPlatform',
  'RequestsService',
  function($rootScope, ngCart, ngCartItem, store, $window,
    $ionicPlatform, RequestsService) {
   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    window.onNotification = function(e) {

     console.log('notification received');

     switch (e.event) {
     case 'registered':
      if (e.regid.length > 0) {
       var device_token = e.regid;
       alert(device_token);
       RequestsService.register(device_token).then(
         function(response) {
          alert(JSON.stringify(response));
          alert("register!");
         });
      }
      break;
     case 'message':
      alert('msg received');
      alert(JSON.stringify(e));
      break;

     case 'error':
      alert('error occured');
      break;
     }
    };
    window.errorHandler = function(error) {
     alert('an error occured');
    }

    pushNotification.register(onNotification, errorHandler, {
     'badge' : 'true',
     'sound' : 'true',
     'alert' : 'true',
     'senderID' : 'your sender id',
     'ecb' : 'onNotification'
    });

   });
   $rootScope.$cart = {
    items : []
   };
   if (angular.isObject(store.get('cart'))) {
    ngCart.$restore(store.get('cart'));
   } else {
    ngCart.init();
   }
  } ]);
```

My index.html :-

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
<head>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport"
 content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title>App-name</title>

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
 src="js/PushNotification.js"></script>
  
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/checklist-model.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/cart.js"></script>
<script src="js/RequestsService.js"></script>

<script src="js/angular-translate.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

 <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my RequestsSerice.js :-

http://piratepad.net/ep/pad/view/ro.B4M$J6oZcip/latest

I would like to tell you that initially every thing was working fine but after updating cordova to latest version my app stops functioning.

I have checked the spellings too , but still getting the above error while running the code.

Comment: Where is your **RequestsService** defined?

Comment: How is your `RequestsService` defined?

Comment: so you just silently removed RequestsService from the config of your app. Nice Job Bud!

Comment: Hey , Yerken , that was done by mistake i put the testing code in that first , just after your comment , i noticed that , so i just replaced it with new one which i was using in my eclipse .

Comment: Well that helps me too , But the main reason why it was not working was due to updated cordova , As in this version i can not just continue my codding from eclipse , i need to open the file first  from its existing location  and need to build that , previously my code was getting vanished automatically after build , so during my R&D i found the way to deal with new cordova.

Comment: Basically that solve my issue as i mention that previously my code was working ....this problem occurs only after updating my cordova.I do appreciate your help buddy.Thanks for giving your valuable time to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put

```
<script src="js/RequestsService.js"></script>
```

before

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Like this

```
<script src="js/RequestsService.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use RequestsService at config stage of your angular app. 
What is the use case for this? More information would be helpful